# Spring-Boot and DialogFlow : Why I receive an anonymous request on my webhook defined in DialogFlow?

Tags: spring-boot, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm creating a web application with Spring Boot that defines a REST API accessible via OAuth2 authentication for use with Google Assistant
I configured DialogFlow (Webhook fulfillment configured with the URL to the endpoint of my REST API)
I configured Actions on Google: I configured the Account Linking section with OAuth information (client ID, client Secret, Authorization URL, Token URL, Scopes ...)

I tested my application with my smartphone via the Google Home application.
It tells me: "Before I can use "My App", I need to associate your "My App" account with Google. Do you agree with that?"
I say, "Yes."
I then have access to my web application for OAuth authentication.
I validate, and it says: "Perfect! Your "My App" account is now connected to Google"

Then I write the sentence "Turn on my TV", it then calls the fulfillment webhook that calls my REST API.

Only I'm getting a request that doesn't seem right. I have an error indicating that the user is anonymous. It is as if the access-token had not been transmitted in the'Authorization' header.
I can't find a way to get the complete request (Header + Body) that is sent.

I also tested on the Actions on Google Simulator but I only see the request body, not the headers. I looked at Google's logs but I don't have any more details.

Here are the logs :

```
19:47:41.263 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /api/fulfillment' doesn't match 'GET /**
19:47:41.264 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/api/fulfillment' matched by universal pattern '/**'
19:47:41.264 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/fulfillment; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(#oauth2.hasScope('write'))]
19:47:41.264 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@2629f42a: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffc434: RemoteIpAddress: 35.184.134.60; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
19:47:41.268 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient scope for this resource
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.throwOnError(OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:120)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:111)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:391)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:89)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:116)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:306)
        at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:33)
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InsufficientScopeException: Insufficient scope for this resource
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.throwOnError(OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.java:71)
        ... 81 common frames omitted
19:47:41.271 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
19:47:41.275 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer - Written [error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@1ff3a97]
19:47:41.276 [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I tested on "OAuth 2.0 Playground" (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground), and it works perfectly!

Is this due to the fact that my App hasn't been released and I'm still in test mode?
Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: If you're doing a smart home action like turning on a TV, I'd suggest you take a look at directly integrating smart home: http://developers.google.com/smarthome

Comment: I looked at smart home and I saw that it was necessary to activate Traits.
But I also want to be able to change the channel and I haven't seen any Traits to do that.
I don't know if that's problematic, but I didn't choose that.
Do you think it's a problem or is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose right now that's not going to work, but better TV support is something that was announced at I/O, so keep this in the back of your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Google isn't sending the bearer token in the Authorization header (for various reasons, but at least partially because some services are using this to authorize the service - not the user of the service). It sends it as part of the JSON body.

If you are using the Action SDK, you'll find this in `user.accessToken`. In Dialogflow, this will be under `originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.accessToken`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand better why it doesn't work.

However, in the documentation, [link](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow), the following is written in the "Handle data access requests" section:

... Google might make the following request to your service:

GET /mycontent HTTP/1.1
Host: myservice.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN

Maybe it's only for Google Smart Home?

Comment: Yeah, that is generic documentation. Other sections talk about how the data is sent specifically. There is an open bug to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Following Prisoner's answer, I created a custom `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.TokenExtractor` to manage the access-token present in the request body.

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
class BodyTokenExtractor : BearerTokenExtractor() {

    private val logger = LogFactory.getLog(BodyTokenExtractor::class.java)

    override fun extractToken(request: HttpServletRequest): String? {
        var token: String? = null

        if (HttpMethod.POST.matches(request.method)) {
            token = extractBodyToken(request)
        }

        if (token == null) {
            logger.debug("Token not found in body. Trying request headers.")
            token = super.extractToken(request)
        } else {
            request.setAttribute(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE, OAuth2AccessToken.BEARER_TYPE)
        }

        return token
    }

    /**
     * Extract the OAuth token from the request body.
     *
     * @param request The request.
     * @return The token, or null if no OAuth authorization header was supplied.
     */
    protected fun extractBodyToken(request: HttpServletRequest): String? {
        try {
            val requestBody = IOUtils.toString(request.reader)
            val request = JacksonFactory().fromString(requestBody, Map::class.java)
            val originalDetectIntentRequest = request["originalDetectIntentRequest"] as Map<String, Object>
            if (originalDetectIntentRequest != null) {
                val payload = originalDetectIntentRequest["payload"] as Map<String, Object>
                if (payload != null) {
                    val user = payload["user"] as Map<String, Object>
                    if (user != null) {
                        return user["accessToken"] as String?
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            logger.debug("An error occurred while reading the request body: " + e.message, e)
        }
        return null
    }

}
```

This class is then called in the Resource Server :

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class OAuthResourceServerConfig() : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    ...
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(resources: ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        resources.resourceId(resourceId).tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenExtractor(tokenExtractor())
    }

    private fun tokenStore(): TokenStore {
        return JdbcTokenStore(dataSource)
    }

    private fun tokenExtractor(): TokenExtractor {
        return BodyTokenExtractor()
    }
   ...
}
```

It is important to define a custom filter to allow to read multiple times the request body :

```
@Bean
fun multiReadFilter(): FilterRegistrationBean<*> {
    val registrationBean = FilterRegistrationBean<CachedRequestWrapperFilter>()
    val multiReadRequestFilter = CachedRequestWrapperFilter()
    registrationBean.filter = multiReadRequestFilter
    registrationBean.order = SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER - 2
    registrationBean.urlPatterns = Arrays.asList("/api/*")
    return registrationBean
}

class CachedRequestWrapperFilter : Filter {
    @Throws(ServletException::class)
    override fun init(config: FilterConfig) {
        // nothing goes here
    }

    @Throws(java.io.IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        val requestWrapper = CachedHttpServletRequest(request as HttpServletRequest)
        // Pass request back down the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response)
    }

    override fun destroy() {
        /* Called before the Filter instance is removed from service by the web container*/
    }
}

public class CachedHttpServletRequestextends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream cachedContent;

    public CachedHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        // Read the request body and populate the cachedContent
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        // Create input stream from cachedContent
        // and return it
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        // Create a reader from cachedContent
        // and return it
    }
}
```

There are plenty of examples explaining how to wrap the request and read multiple times.
Example: http://www.myjavarecipes.com/tag/how-to-read-request-twice/

By doing that, it works perfectly!